# Meaning of "I am holding for"

Tags: conversation

I was watching "Gilmore Girls"

Lory (Lorelai's daughter) just got in private school, but Lorelai discovered that tuition enroll fee is too much high to prepare on short notice. So I think, she decided to call school management(Ms Bell) to ask if there's any other option. and here's the line of phone call.

Lorelai :I'm holding for Miss Bell. I've been trying all day.

Now, While I know this could mean that she has been looking to connect with Miss Bell whole day, I am kind of confused with use of "holding" here.
I know "hold" when in phone call, it's mostly used for " wait for" like "hold on please" .

Is the "hold for" is colloquial way of saying "I was waiting to connect to this person whole day"?
Thank you for your reply in advance!!

Comment: You’re quoting a phone call, and you know what the phrase means in the context of a phone call. What do you not understand?

Comment: @Scott First let me say, thank you for saying that I have understood this phone call. In the context of, one can always easily understand it and maybe assume that digested it and easily pass it. But what I'm trying to do is to understand it correctly so that next time I could use it in exact situation. And what I was wondering is that I couldn't find in any part of dictionary that seems to clearly connect to meaning which "hold" here worked. And you may not noticed above the question mark ?-  " Is the "hold for" is colloquial way of saying "I was waiting to be able to connect to you?.

Comment: If you are holding for someone then you are on the phone. You’ve dialed the number and someone has answered but the person you wish to speak with is not ready to talk with you yet. So you stay on the line while they swig their phone to as different line to conclude their other business.  You’re on hold.  If you hang up, you are no longer holding for them even if you still wish to try again later.

Comment: @Jim thank you for clearing it up! I thought it has kind of different meaning in this situation.

Comment: @Jim That's true, but I suspect that the quoted line was spoken to someone other than Miss Bell (possibly a junior member of her team) who had picked up the call from the queue and said something like "I'm Alice, a member of the management team. Can I help you?" Lorelai is saying in response that she prefers to wait until Miss Bell is available.

Comment: @Jim and Dianne. Jim’s comment should be an answer. Then Dianne could accept it.

Comment: @BoldBen - Yes, that’s quite possible.

Comment: @BoldBen thank you so much for giving deeper context on this. I didn't realize who she is exactly talking to since the scene only shows Lorelai answering the phone call. Now it is more clear.